# How to change font size and type in the middle of a R markdown document?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

Example:

```
---
output: pdf_document
mainfont: Times New Roman
fontsize: 12pt
spacing: 1.1
geometry: "left=1in,right=1in,top=0.5in,bottom=1in"
vspace: 4pt
---

This line is normal text.

This line uses Garamond font and font size 14.

This line uses arial font and font size 16.

This line is normal text.
```

I tried a few options and none worked. Please let me know if there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We may use LaTeX codes inside your rmarkdown script. Set the font type with `\fontfamily{}`, some font codes can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document). (Note that I am using Palatino here because Garamond is probably not installed on my system.) Font size can be set with `\fontsize{}{}`, where the first `{}` stands for the size, the second for the spacing. To make this just temporary I suggest to embed it into a `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`. Leave your YAML header as it is.

```
This line is normal text.

\begingroup
\fontfamily{ppl}\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont
This line uses Garamond font and font size 14.
\endgroup

\begingroup
\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{16}{18}\selectfont
This line uses arial font and font size 16.
\endgroup

This line is normal text.
```

#### Result

[image]